# on(click) event delegation .forEach Array.from only shows the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, event-delegation

I'm trying to change the background color of dynamic html elements (`span`) when user clicks them.

```
function showQuestion(){
    for(let i = 0; i < QuesPartA.length; i++){
      $(".questionBox").append('<div class="Question">Number '+ parseInt(i+1) +'</div>');
      QuesPartA[i]['option'].forEach(option => {
          $(".questionBox").append('<span class="pilihan">'+option +' </span><br>');  
      });
  } 

$(".secondBox").append('<a href="Listening Part A.html" class="btnToPartB">Continue to Part B</a>');
  };

$(".questionBox").on("click", "span.pilihan", function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("pilihan"))
  .forEach((element) => element.style.backgroundColor = "red");
    });
```

However, I want only the one clicked that changes color, not all `span.pilihan`, but my code above change the color off all to be red.

Any idea?

Comment: _"but my code above change the color off all to be red"_ - Because that's exactly what you've told the script to do... -> `Array.from(...).forEach(...)`

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center -> Events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/), [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Any ideas how to change only the one clicked? @Andreas

Comment: Sure. You will also get one if you check the links I've added in my second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this:

```
 $(".questionBox").on("click", ".pilihan", function() {
  $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```